tkraise() issue with background
I'm using tkraise() to switch between sign-in page and sign-up page, but the problem is that in the first part of my code (sign up), it didn't show the background image, while the second part (sign-in) works fine.
Can someone help me with this problem.
This is my code:
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk

accountSystem=Tk()

accountSystem.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

accountSystem.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

accountSystem.geometry('1280x720+128+72')

accountSystem.title('ACCOUNT SYSTEM')

#Navigating through windows

sign_in=Frame(accountSystem)

sign_up=Frame(accountSystem)

for frame in (sign_in, sign_up):

    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

def show_frame(frame):

    frame.tkraise()

show_frame(sign_up)


#-------------------------------------------------------------------
--
#-------------------------FUNCTIONALLY PART-------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

def hide():

    openeye.config(file='images/close_eye.png')

    passwordEntry.config(show='*')

    eyeButton.config(command=show)


def show():

    openeye.config(file='images/open_eye.png')

    passwordEntry.config(show='')

    eyeButton.config(command=hide)


def user_enter(event):

    if usernameEntry.get()=='Username':

        usernameEntry.delete(0, END)


def password_enter(event):

    if passwordEntry.get()=='Password':

        passwordEntry.delete(0, END)

def confirmpassword_enter(event):

    if confirmpasswordEntry.get()=='Conform Password':

        confirmpasswordEntry.delete(0, END)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------

#----------------SIGN UP----------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#-----BACKGROUND IMAGE-----

bgImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='images/1_signup.png')

bgLabel=Label(sign_up, image=bgImage)

bgLabel.place(x=0, y=0)


heading=Label(sign_up, text='Sign up', font=('Open Sans', 26, 'bold') ,bg='SlateBlue1', fg='white')

heading.place(x=795, y=188)

#-----USERNAME-----

usernameEntry=Entry(sign_up, width=27, font=('Open Sans', 14, 'bold'),bg='SlateBlue1',fg='white', bd=0)

usernameEntry.place(x=705, y=275)

usernameEntry.insert(0, 'Username')

usernameEntry.bind('<FocusIn>', user_enter)

#-----PASSWORD-----

passwordEntry=Entry(sign_in, width=25, font=('Open Sans', 14, 'bold'),bg='SlateBlue1',fg='white', bd=0)

passwordEntry.place(x=705, y=340)

passwordEntry.insert(0, 'Password')

passwordEntry.bind('<FocusIn>', password_enter)

openeye=PhotoImage(file='images/open_eye.png')

eyeButton=Button(sign_up, image=openeye, bd=0, bg='SlateBlue1', activebackground='SlateBlue1',cursor='hand2', command=hide)

eyeButton.place(x=980, y=340)

#-----CONFIRM PASSWORD-----

confirmpasswordEntry=Entry(sign_up, width=25, font=('Open Sans', 14, 'bold'),bg='SlateBlue1',fg='white', bd=0)

confirmpasswordEntry.place(x=705, y=410)

confirmpasswordEntry.insert(0, 'Conform Password')

confirmpasswordEntry.bind('<FocusIn>', confirmpassword_enter)

#REGISTER BUTTON----

registerButton=Button(sign_up, text='Register', font=('Open Sans', 16, 'bold') ,bg='SlateBlue1', fg='white', activeforeground='white', activebackground='SlateBlue1', cursor='hand2', bd=0)

registerButton.place(x=815, y=475)

#----SWITCH INTO LOGIN PAGE-----
loginLabel=Label(sign_up, text="Already have an account?", font=('Open Sans', 9, 'bold'),bg='SlateBlue3', fg='white', bd=0)

loginLabel.place(x=770,y=532)

loginButton=Button(sign_up, text='Login', font=('Open Sans', 9, 'bold underline'),fg='white', bg='SlateBlue3', activeforeground='white', activebackground='SlateBlue3', cursor='hand2', bd=0, command=lambda : show_frame(sign_in))
loginButton.place(x=920, y=530)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#----------------SIGN IN----------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#-----BACKGROUND IMAGE-----

bgImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='images/1_signin.png')

bgLabel=Label(sign_in, image=bgImage)

bgLabel.place(x=0, y=0)

heading=Label(sign_in, text='Sign in', font=('Open Sans', 26, 'bold') ,bg='SlateBlue1', fg='white')

heading.place(x=815, y=190)

#-----USERNAME------

usernameEntry=Entry(sign_in, width=27, font=('Open Sans', 14, 'bold'),bg='SlateBlue1',fg='white', bd=0)

usernameEntry.place(x=720, y=305)

usernameEntry.insert(0, 'Username')

usernameEntry.bind('<FocusIn>', user_enter)

#-----PASSWORD-----

passwordEntry=Entry(sign_in, width=25, font=('Open Sans', 14, 'bold') ,bg='SlateBlue1',fg='white', bd=0)

passwordEntry.place(x=720, y=380)

passwordEntry.insert(0, 'Password')

passwordEntry.bind('<FocusIn>', password_enter)

openeye=PhotoImage(file='images/open_eye.png')

eyeButton=Button(sign_in, image=openeye, bd=0, bg='SlateBlue1', activebackground='SlateBlue1'
                 ,cursor='hand2', command=hide)
eyeButton.place(x=1000, y=380)

#-----FORGET PASSWORD-----

forgetButton=Button(sign_in, text='Forget Password?', bd=0, bg='SlateBlue3', activebackground='SlateBlue3',cursor='hand2', font=('Open Sans', 10, 'bold'), fg='white', activeforeground='white')
forgetButton.place(x=715, y=460)

#-----lOGIN BUTTON-----

loginButton=Button(sign_in, text='Login', font=('Open Sans', 16, 'bold') ,bg='SlateBlue1', fg='white', activeforeground='white', activebackground='SlateBlue1', cursor='hand2', bd=0)

loginButton.place(x=925, y=455)

#-----SWITCH INTO REGISTER-----

signupLabel=Label(sign_in, text="Don't have an account?", font=('Open Sans', 9, 'bold'), bg='SlateBlue3', fg='white', bd=0)
signupLabel.place(x=730, y=522)

signupButton=Button(sign_in, text='Creat new account', font=('Open Sans', 9, 'bold underline'),fg='white', bg='SlateBlue3', activeforeground='white', activebackground='SlateBlue3', cursor='hand2', bd=0, command=lambda : show_frame(sign_up))

signupButton.place(x=870, y=520)

accountSystem.resizable(0,0)

accountSystem.mainloop()

I've changed the order of the sign in and sign up part (put the sign in part above the sign up part). But no matter which part I've changed, it is always the first part of the code that its background image didn't show up.

Try to create an MRE and show it as properly formatted text in the question.

you didn't show code so we can't help. Maybe your problem is different. Tkinter has problem with images if you assign image to local variable inside function - because garbage collector can remove it from memory when you exit function. It doesn't show any error but it can't display image. And it needs to assign image to global variable or class variable. OR maybe you put image in wrong place - so it can't be raised

I'm so sorry, I've added my code

Just as a side note I'd really recommend using import tkinter as tk in case you decide to use tix or ttk widgets in future.  Better to refactor your code now than when it gets bigger (lesson learned the hard way).  Just change to tk.Tk() etc.



but the problem is the first part of my code (sign up), it didn't show
the background image,

while the second part (sign in) works fine

The problem can be fixed.
In line 86, add this:
bgLabel=Label(sign_up,  image=bgImage)
bgLabel.image = bgImage #<= Add this, so we can see on fly.

In line 107, The frame should be sign_up not sign_in
passwordEntry=Entry(sign_up, ..)

That all. You ready to go.
Screenshot:

